# Adding to a value in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble with the following code.  I need to add a key to a python dictionary if it does not exist, and if it does then I need to add to the value.
My output should look like this.

```
{'STA': {'value':-62**.***, 'count': 4}}.....
```

But I'm getting this instead.

```
{'STA': {'value': -1194.14562548, 'count': 0}}, 
{'STA': {'value': -5122.985396600001, 'count': 0}}, 
{'STA': {'value': 25.2293, 'count': 0}}, 
{'STA': {'value': 34.0099, 'count': 0}},
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
new_dict = []
for item in sales_orders['progress_output']:
    ex = (list(filter(lambda ex:ex['_branch_shortname'].strip() == item['_branch_shortname'].strip(), expenses)))
    value = float(item['gross_profit'].strip().replace(',', '')) - (float(item['load_factor_extended'].strip().replace(',', '')) * float(ex[0]['value']))
    branch = item['_branch_shortname'].strip()

    if branch in new_dict:
        new_dict[branch]['value'] += value
        new_dict[branch]['count'] += 1
    else:
        new_dict.append({branch: {'value': value, 'count': 0}})

    #print(item['_branch_shortname'], value)
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: do as `new_dict[branch]= {'value': value, 'count': 0}`

Comment: In Python normal `dict` is not ordered sequence, there is no append.

Comment: `new_dict` is a list. Change `[]` to `{}` and it will be declared as an empty dictionary. Better yet, use `dict()`.

Comment: Grijesh, that was the answer I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Ken, I also took your suggestion and added  new_dict = dict()

Answer (score 1):

You can use setdefault to ensure there is a default value, `setdefault` returns the value if it already exists for key (first parameter) or adds the default (second parameter) and returns it:

```
 new_dict = {}
 for ...:
     b  = new_dict.setdefault(branch, {'value': 0, 'count': 0})
     b['value'] += value
     b['count'] += 1
```

You can also use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'value': 0, 'count': 0})
for ...:
    new_dict[branch]['value'] += value
    new_dict[branch]['count'] += 1
```